# Simplify Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have 64 columns to be used to modify data when amendment is required, is there any way to simplify this script? I'm worried it will affect the performance

```
function updateData() {
var SEARCH_COL_year = 0;
var SEARCH_COL_hospital = 1;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Data Entry Form");

  var hospital = formSS.getRange("B7").getValue();
  var year = formSS.getRange("D7").getValue();

  ["Hospital Simunjan","Hospital Lundu"].forEach(function(s) {
  var values = ss.getSheetByName(s).getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var row = values[i];
     if ((row[SEARCH_COL_year] == year)){
      var INT_R = i+1;
      var values1 = [[formSS.getRange("D7").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("H25").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("M25").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("R25").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("W25").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AB25").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AG25").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AL25").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AQ25").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AV25").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BA25").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BF25").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BK25").getValue()]];
                      ss.getSheetByName(s).getRange(INT_R,1, 1, 13).setValues(values1);
     }
  }
  });

  var values = ss.getSheetByName("Billing Masterlist").getDataRange().getValues();
  var cont = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var row = values[i];
    if ((row[SEARCH_COL_year] == year && row[SEARCH_COL_hospital] == hospital )){
    var INT_R = i+1;

      var s = (11 + cont).toString();
      var values1 = [[formSS.getRange("D7").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("B7").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("B" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("D" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("E" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("F" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("G" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("H" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("I" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("J" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("K" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("L" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("M" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("N" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("O" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("P" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("Q" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("R" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("S" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("T" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("U" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("V" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("W" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("X" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("Y" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("Z" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AA" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AB" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AC" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AD" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AE" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AF" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AG" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AH" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AI" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AJ" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AK" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AL" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AM" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AN" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AO" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AP" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AQ" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AR" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AS" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AT" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AU" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AV" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AW" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AX" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AY" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("AZ" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BA" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BB" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BC" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BD" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BE" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BF" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BG" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BH" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BI" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BJ" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BK" + s).getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("BL" + s).getValue()]];
                      ss.getSheetByName("Billing Masterlist").getRange(INT_R,1, 1, 64).setValues(values1);
                      cont = cont + 1;


      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(' "Data Updated" ');
    }
  }
}
```

I already try changing this script from **formSS.getRange("B" + s).getValue()**, to **formSS.getRange("B:BL" + s).getValue()**, but non of it is working.

**Added Information as References:**

For better understanding, I provide you the steps for using my dashboard

1. Fill data using the `Data Entry Form` sheet
2. Press the Submit Button (Data will be saved inside the `Billing Masterlist` and `Hospital sheet`)
3. If there is any modification to the previously submitted data, then you have to `Search` the data by providing the information in `Data Entry Form` (Columns `B7 & D7`) and press the `Search Button`
4. Once Searched is completed, it will show the data you wanted to edit, so after you edit the data, it will edit data inside `Billing Masterlist` as well after you press the `Modify` button

I wanted to make the the script for `Modify` button as simple as it could since the script I provided you is too long, is there any way to make it simpler and give the same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure about your variable of `values`, if your showing script works fine, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please replace your showing script with the following script.

```js
const [[b7, , d7]] = formSS.getRange("B7:D7").getValues();
const v = formSS.getRange("B11:BL" + formSS.getLastRow()).getValues();
let count = 0;
const res = values.map((row, i) => {
  const c = row[SEARCH_COL_year] == year && row[SEARCH_COL_hospital] == hospital;
  if (c && v[i]) {
    const [b, , ...d] = v[count];
    count++;
    return [d7, b7, b, ...d];
  }
  return Array(64).fill(null);
});
ss.getSheetByName("Billing Masterlist").getRange(1, 1, res.length, 64).setValues(res);
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your showing script works fine. Please be careful about this.
- When I tested your showing script with a sample value of `values`, I confirmed that the result is the same with the above-modified script. But, if this modified script was not your expected result, it is required to know your actual expected result using the sample input and output situations.

### Added:

From your provided Spreadsheet, how about the following modification? In this case, please replace your script below the line of `var cont = 0;` as follows.

```js
const [[b7, , d7]] = formSS.getRange("B7:D7").getValues();
const v = formSS.getRange("B11:BL" + formSS.getLastRow()).getValues();
let count = 0;
const res = values.map(row => {
  const c = row[SEARCH_COL_year] == year && row[SEARCH_COL_hospital] == hospital;
  if (c) {
    const [b, , ...d] = v[count];
    count++;
    return [d7, b7, b, ...d];
  }
  return row;
});
ss.getSheetByName("Billing Masterlist").getRange(1, 1, res.length, 64).setValues(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but the modified code is not the same as the output I wanted it to be. 

The code should amend only the chosen data. Is there any way to simplify it as the code I'm currently written is too long. I already uploaded the full code under my question for your reference. Please review

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel Thank you for replying. About your reply, I have to apologize for my very poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do from your reply. But, I understand that my guess of your initial question was not correct. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the sample input and output situations? By this, I would like to confirm your actual expected result. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Sure here is the sample sheet as requested 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CyALo_tE_75w1SCPCIiiqgToyYRAnZJKMdpBpW6G5mY/edit#gid=1949705865

Th current code i used for data update/modify iS working fine but i wanted the code to be more simple if possible.

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot open it. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: Can you open it now ? I already set to public

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel Thank you for replying. I could open it. I checked your script. Please wait for it.

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel By the way, now I noticed that your script was changed. In your actual question, do you want to modify the below the line of `var cont = 0;` in your initial question? Or, do you want to modify your updated script?

Comment: Only the var cont = 0;

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel Thank you for replying. From `Only the var cont = 0;`, I understood that you wanted to modify the below the line of `var cont = 0;`. By the way, can I think of that your showing script worked fine? Because, when I tested your showing script with your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that only the last row of "Billing Masterlist" sheet is updated. You don't want to append the new value to "Billing Masterlist" sheet. You want to update only the last row of "Billing Masterlist" sheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I've added another information to my question for your better understanding

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, the provided script works super fine. Thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256801/discussion-between-cyril-leonel-and-tanaike).